# CRM 2011 import/export error with picklist on entity

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

We have upgraded a CRM 4 to CRM 2011 instance and everything is running great.

Now we want to move over our customization from our dev environment to production.

I'm attempting to use solutions but getting this error.

> Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: Picklist option with value (100000000) that has the parent OptionSet with (c5be69cf-f4bf-4c80-9440-832a7f044498) id does not exist. Default picklist value has to be one of the option values.

Just to try to troubleshoot, move past this, I removed the entity from the solution and now getting another error which may or may not be related.

> This import has failed because a different entity with the identical name, ct_plantype,already exists in the target organization.

Comment: Thanks for the formatting help Otiel!

Comment: You can find the OptionSet in question by querying the table called OptionSetView (SELECT OptionSetId, Name FROM OptionSetView WHERE OptionSetId ='guid goes here'. Is your Prod environment completely new (no previous deployments from other dev servers)?

Comment: This is a new production environment so it's not technically production yet. We blew it away the vanilla org and copied our CRM4 DB and used the deployment manager wizard to import/upgrade it.

Comment: There is KB article here for your exact error message (http://blog.dorrekens.com/index.php/list/71-latest-kb-articles-for-40-and-2011) CTRL+F for 'The import has failed because a different entity'. I however cannot access the article to suggest how useful it is or isn't (sorry)

Comment: Yup. Only like 2 google results are available and that list was one of them, which I cannot access either. TY for the help though. MSDN forums are also currently having issue so cant hit most of the pages.

Comment: Is frustrating MS want to hide information like that away, I guess they have to keep something back for subscribers. If I can grab the details at work tomorrow I will and post up anything useful I find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just ended up deleting it from our target and just letting it get updated during the import.

Unfortunately, we'll need to go in and remap a bunch of data.